# Decide FontStyle (Bold, Italic, Underlined) for RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

How exactly do you change the Font in a RichTextBox?

Looking around gives me old answers that doesn't seem to work any more. I thought it would be as simple as doing `richtextbox1.Font = Font.Bold;` or something similar. Turns out it's not, so I looked around. Apparently you have to change the `FontStyle` which is a `readonly` (??) property, but you have to do it making a new `FontStyle` Object.

But even then that doesn't work o.o

How do you do this?
EDIT:

Doesn't seem to work :\

```
            rssTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
            rssTextBox.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            rssTextBox.AppendText("Title: ");
            rssTextBox.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
            rssTextBox.AppendText(rs.Title + "\n");
            rssTextBox.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            rssTextBox.AppendText("Publication Date: ");
            rssTextBox.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
            rssTextBox.AppendText(rs.PublicationDate + "\n");
            rssTextBox.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            rssTextBox.AppendText("Description: ");
            rssTextBox.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
            rssTextBox.AppendText(rs.Description + "\n\n");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bold` is a `FontWeight`. You can apply it directly.

As [MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontweight.aspx) states "Gets or sets the weight or thickness of the specified font."

You can either set it in xaml

```
<RichTextBox FontWeight="Bold" x:Name="richText" />
```

or in codebehind:

```
richText.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
```

If your trying to switch `FontFamily` that would be like:

```
richText.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
```

or `FontStyle`:

```
richText.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
```

**Update**: (for updating `RichTextBox` inline)

This is just a quick mock-up. Using this as an example. Please structure it for your requirements.

```
richText.Document.Blocks.Clear();
Paragraph textParagraph = new Paragraph();
AddInLineBoldText("Title: ", ref textParagraph);
AddNormalTextWithBreak(rs.Title, ref textParagraph);
AddInLineBoldText("Publication Date: ", ref textParagraph);
AddNormalTextWithBreak(rs.PublicationDate, ref textParagraph);
AddInLineBoldText("Description: ", ref textParagraph);
AddNormalTextWithBreak(rs.Description, ref textParagraph);
AddNormalTextWithBreak("", ref textParagraph);
richText.Document.Blocks.Add(textParagraph);

private static void AddInLineBoldText(string text, ref Paragraph paragraph) {
  Bold myBold = new Bold();
  myBold.Inlines.Add(text);
  paragraph.Inlines.Add(myBold);
}

private static void AddNormalTextWithBreak(string text, ref Paragraph paragraph) {
  Run myRun = new Run {Text = text + Environment.NewLine};
  paragraph.Inlines.Add(myRun);
}
```

Comment: No it works exactly as expected. Setting FontWeight to Bold / Normal applies to entire Control. not just for what your going to add henceforth. What you need is in-line formatting. I'll update my answer with a sample for your usage

Comment: @Vipar Have updated my answer with a quick mockup to do what you require. Do look into FlowDocument and apply it to suit your requirements accordingly.